Azure SQL Elastic Job - Failed to connect to the target database: Login failed for user 'jobuser'
I'm trying to create an azure elastic job base and agent with Powershell. I'm looking at the Microsoft documentation: Create and manage elastic jobs by using PowerShell and following it. I want to use database-scoped credentials for the login
Everything seems to be created without problems, but when I run the job  I get an error about login failed for jobuser.
I'm a bit stuck and don't know where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!
Here are my scripts.


The first script creates a database and an agent and to it the user admin and jobuser, then it creates credentials, a target group, and the jobs themselves

The second script checks if the user exists, if not, adds him and gives him db_owner rights, I tried alter rights or create, but it had no effect. The idea of ​​the second script is that I have a lot of databases and I don't want to manually add them. Also, i want to separate creating and adding users


Write-Host "Creating AgentJob Database"

$rgName = "<resourcegroup-name>"
$sqlServer = "<sqlserver>"
$jobDatabaseName = "AgentDB"
$jobAdminPassword = "adminPassword"
$adminLogin = 'myadminuser'
$adminPassword = 'strongpassword'
$jobUserPassword = 'jobuserpassword'

$parameters = @{
    ResourceGroupName = $rgName 
    ServerName = $sqlServer 
    DatabaseName = $jobDatabaseName 
    RequestedServiceObjectiveName = "S1"
}
$jobDatabase = New-AzSqlDatabase @parameters
Write-Output "Creating job agent"
$agentName = "elasticagent"
$parameters = @{
    Name = $agentName 
}

$jobAgent = $jobDatabase | New-AzSqlElasticJobAgent @parameters

$params = @{
  'database' = 'master'
  'serverInstance' =  $sqlServer + '.database.windows.net'
  'username' = $adminLogin
  'password' = $adminPassword
  'outputSqlErrors' = $true
  'query' = "CREATE LOGIN adminjobuser WITH PASSWORD='$jobAdminPassword'"
}

Invoke-SqlCmd @params
Write-Host "Creating adminjobuser to master db"
$params.query = "CREATE USER adminjobuser FROM LOGIN adminjobuser"
Invoke-SqlCmd @params
Write-Host "Creating jobuser to master db"
$params.query = "CREATE LOGIN jobuser WITH PASSWORD='$jobUserPassword'"
Invoke-SqlCmd @params

# Create job credential in job database for admin user and jobuser
Write-Output "Creating job credentials to AgentDB"
$loginPasswordSecure = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '$jobUserPassword' -AsPlainText -Force)
$loginadminuserPasswordSecure = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '$jobAdminPassword' -AsPlainText -Force)

$adminCred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList "adminjobuser", $loginadminuserPasswordSecure
$adminCred = $jobAgent | New-AzSqlElasticJobCredential -Name "adminjobuser" -Credential $adminCred

$jobCred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList "jobuser", $loginPasswordSecure
$jobCred = $jobAgent | New-AzSqlElasticJobCredential -Name "jobuser" -Credential $jobCred

Write-Output "Creating Europe and USA target groups..."
$serverUSAGroup = $jobAgent | New-AzSqlElasticJobTargetGroup -Name 'USAGroup'
$serverEuropeGroup = $jobAgent | New-AzSqlElasticJobTargetGroup -Name 'EuropeGroup'

Write-Output "Creating a new job for USA Databases"
$jobNameUsa = "Maintenance USA Databases"
$jobUsa = $jobAgent | New-AzSqlElasticJob -Name $jobNameUsa -RunOnce

Write-Output "Creating a new job for Europe Databases"
$jobNameEurope = "Maintenance Europe Databases"
$jobEurope = $jobAgent | New-AzSqlElasticJob -Name $jobNameEurope -RunOnce

$sqlScript = Get-Content -Path 'C:\myscripts\maintanace-indexes.sql' -Raw

Write-Output "Creating job steps for Main Databases"
$jobUsa | Add-AzSqlElasticJobStep -Name "Rebuild or Reorginize Indexes" -TargetGroupName $serverUSAGroup.TargetGroupName -CredentialName $jobCred.CredentialName -CommandText $sqlscript

Write-Output "Creating job steps for Secondary Databases"
$jobEurope | Add-AzSqlElasticJobStep -Name "Rebuild or Reorginize Indexes" -TargetGroupName $serverEuropeGroup.TargetGroupName -CredentialName $jobCred.CredentialName -CommandText $sqlscript

Write-Host "Creating time schedules for both jobs"
$intervalType = "Week"
$intervalCount = 1  # Once a week

# Set the start time for the first schedule to the next Sunday at 02:00 AM UTC
$currentDate = Get-Date
$nextSunday = $currentDate.AddDays(7 - [int]$currentDate.DayOfWeek)
$startTimeLocalEurope = Get-Date -Year $nextSunday.Year -Month $nextSunday.Month -Day $nextSunday.Day -Hour 2 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$startTimeUtcEurope = $startTimeLocalEurope.ToUniversalTime()

# Set the start time for the second schedule to the next Sunday at 11:00 PM UTC
$startTimeLocalUSA = Get-Date -Year $nextSunday.Year -Month $nextSunday.Month -Day $nextSunday.Day -Hour 23 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$startTimeUtcUSA = $startTimeLocalUSA.ToUniversalTime()

# Set the schedule for the jobs
$jobEurope | Set-AzSqlElasticJob -IntervalType $intervalType -IntervalCount $intervalCount -StartTime $startTimeUtcEurope -Enable
$jobUsa | Set-AzSqlElasticJob -IntervalType $intervalType -IntervalCount $intervalCount -StartTime $startTimeUtcUSA -Enable 


$targetServer = '<sqlServer>'
$adminLogin = 'myadminuser'
$adminPassword = 'adminpassword'
$agentUser = 'jobuser'
$dbsToExclude = @('master')

$params = @{
  'database' = 'master'
  'serverInstance' =  $targetServer + '.database.windows.net'
  'username' = $adminLogin
  'password' = $adminPassword
  'outputSqlErrors' = $true
  'query' = "SELECT name FROM sys.databases"
}

$dbNames = Invoke-SqlCmd @params
$dbNamesFiltered = $dbNames | Where-Object { $_.name -notmatch '[_-]'}

foreach ($dbName in $dbNamesFiltered)
{
   $currentDb = $dbName.name
   $params.database = $currentDb
   $params.query = "SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = '$($agentUser)' AND type = 'S'"
    
   $userCheck = Invoke-SqlCmd @params

   if (-not $userCheck) 
   {
     Write-Host "Creating jobuser in database: $currentDb"
     $params.query = "CREATE USER $agentUser FOR LOGIN $agentUser"
     Invoke-SqlCmd @params
     Write-Host "Adding jobuser with db_owner role for database: $currentDb"
     $params.query = "ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER $agentUser;"
     Invoke-SqlCmd @params

   } 
   else 
   {
     Write-Host "jobuser already exists in database: $currentDb"
   }
}

Manually added via Azure portal to target group SQL Database with the SQL server name and the following db.

When I run the job from Azure Portal.I notice that I can't log in. When I try it through SSMS I succeed

Here is the credentials as well.


Please create the credential (password) without using the character "$". I don't know about more characters not supported as part of the password, but I know the $ character is one of them.

I read about it not being allowed and I didn't include it in the password. Could it be something else

I am sorry I saw you were using the character as part of passwords on the script.

I found the problem when I passed the password as a variable there seems to be a problem. When I hardcode it, it works. Thank you Alberto Morillo for reminding me to look into this with the password. Cheers

I am glad for you.
